# Community ads for other sites, 2017 edition!

Tags: discussion, advertising

Could some artistic people put together some quality community ads to put on other sites?

I'd recommend

[Sci-Fi Community Ads](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10564/community-promotion-ads-2017)
[Roleplaying Community ads](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6717/community-promotion-ads-2017)
and
[Gaming/Arqade Community Ads](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/community-promotion-ads-2017)

So what do people think? Can we do this?